# Splitting a string on two zero-width assertions

Tags: r, regex

I would like to isolate a number within a string by splitting it on two zero-width assertions. I can split on the first

```
strsplit("nursereviewday36_arm_1", "(?<=[[:alpha:]])(?=[[:digit:]])", perl = T)
```

So that it returns

```
[[1]]
[1] "nursereviewday" "36_arm_1"
```

But I would like to split into three like so

```
[[1]]
[1] "nursereviewday" "36" "_arm_1"
```

This is in R but any regex that solves this will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 (?<=[[:alpha:]])(?=[[:digit:]])|(?<=[[:digit:]])(?=_)
```